# How to prove a provided puzzle solution

Tags: geometry, puzzle, pythagorean-triples

Below is a square that is $3 \times 3$ match sticks. You are given 4 match sticks. Assume all match sticks to be of 1 unit dimension.

The puzzle is to use 4 sticks along with the $3\times 3$ square and divide the outer square into two equal parts that look the same and have same area.

The solution is to lay the blue sticks as below. How to mathematically prove it is correct?

[image]

Comment: The two areas are congruent - rotate the square 90 degrees and you get the same figure. So they have the same area. (Thus requires more than a picture - you have to specifically tell us where the matchsticks are going to precisely conclude this.)

Comment: Certainly there are multiple solutions to this puzzle. For example, as the diagonal is larger than $4$, there will be a solution with all $4$ sticks in a straight line.

Comment: And this is not the only solution with this symmetry. You can pick any two matchsticks that start on an edge and end in the center, and then rotate their placement to get the positions of the other edges.

Comment: We are looking for the angle of a, asuuming the top left match and the bottom right match are exactly vertical. One solution is sufficient, however we would be curious how to calculate the angle of a can be calculated with all 4 sticks in a straight line.

Comment: If location of matches is symmetric with respect to square center then solution is correct. Ends of broken line are symmetric, then 1st match must be symmetric to 4th and 2nd must be symmetric to 3rd. Then end of 2nd must be symmetric to begin of 3rd. But end of 2nd is begin of 3rd. Then it is center. Begin of 2nd and end of 3rd are symmetric, then 2nd and 3rd matches must be collinear. Distance from begin of 2nd match to nearest side is not more than $\frac{3-\sqrt{2}}{2} < 1$, then there is point on this side which is not more far than 1. It can be begin of 1st match.

Comment: @jonadv: The angle $\alpha$ in the figure easy enough to find, since the $x$-$y$-$(\text{two matchsticks})$ triangle is half of an equilateral. ... But you don't really *need* to know the exact measure of that angle to conclude that such a symmetric solution —indeed, a family of them— is possible.

Comment: My previous comment does not correspond to solution shown in the picture. For solution in the picture angle is 30°, as hypothenuse is two legs by length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we rotate either half of either square below by $\space 180˚,\space$ we get a figure of the exact size and shape as the other half. This means they are congruent which is mathematics' way of saying they are equal in all respects. There are infinite other solutions, such as a zig-zag down the middle, but these are sufficient for demonstration.

[image]